# How do I expand the positioned Container downwards?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to replicate a design but I am having difficulty doing so. 
On this page, I am trying to stack the blue container over an image and expand it downwards but I can't expand it downwards. I am using weird colours so the contrast can be there to see. I don't want to use a column because it doesn't have the 'stacked' effect. I feel like there is a more elegant way of doing this.

This is what it currently looks like [image]

```
class IndividualNewsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final String articleURL;
  IndividualNewsPage({this.articleURL});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
              child: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Material(
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                            color: Colors.grey,
                          ))),
                  Spacer(),
                  Text(
                    DateFormat.yMMMMd("en_US").format(DateTime.now()),
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black54,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                        fontSize: 15),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                            topRight: Radius.circular(20)),
                        child: Container(
                          height: 400,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.blue,
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                  image: NetworkImage(articleURL),
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 30.0,
                  left: 0,
                  right: 0,
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                            topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                            topLeft: Radius.circular(20))),
                    child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child: Text(
                            "New York",
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                          child: Text(
                              "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I amended the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `Stack` inside an `Expanded` widget. It will fill the available height and the blue widget will be positioned at the bottom of the `Column`.

```dart
...,
Expanded(
    child: Stack(...)
),
...
```

You can set `debugPaintSizeEnabled` to `true` in the main method in order to see Widgets borders, margins, positions... It helps with Widget positioning and sizing problems when building UIs.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart'

void main() {
    debugPaintSizeEnabled = true;
    runApp();
}
```